# mySQL UPDATE all columns from corresponding columns in another table

Tags: mysql, shortcut

I have two tables with identical schema. And lots of columns!

I can update a record from the corresponding table by doing

```
update t1 
join t2 on t2.id=t1.id 
set t1.column1=t2.column1,
    t1.column2=t2.column2... 
where t2.columnx > 123;
```

But I have a ton of fields and am by nature, a lazy bastard who'd rather shave a yak and post on SE than type out a list of columns (possibly missing 1).

Other than some funky solution that writes out the column list to a text file etc, is there valid mySQL syntax that skips the explicit listing of all the columns and works more like INSERT...SELECT?

Answer (score 4):

```
REPLACE INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE columnx>123;
```

Comment: This can add new rows into t1. He need only update existing rows.

Comment: it has to be noted that REPLACE command actually performs a DELETE operation and then an INSERT. this is a crucial difference if your table has foreign keys which could do a DELETE on CASCADE

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `REPLACE INTO ... SELECT ...` syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

```
REPLACE INTO t1 SELECT t2.* FROM t2, t1 WHERE t1.columnx>123 AND t1.id=t2.id;
```

Warning! Not tested!

This code would work only if tables have unique indexes on `id` columns.

Comment: it has to be noted that REPLACE command actually performs a DELETE operation and then an INSERT. this is a crucial difference if your table has foreign keys which could do a DELETE on CASCADE